# Add title to WP Cusomizer Control

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to add title to `add_control` in WordPress after created many automated functions.
How can i add a title to `checkbox` control in WP Customizer.

Here is my setting and control of the selected area:

```
        $wp_customize->add_setting('nav-woocommerce', false);
        $wp_customize->add_control( 'nav-woocommerce', array( 
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'setting' => 'nav-woocommerce',
            'priority' => 25, 
            'section' => 'woo-menus', 
            'label' => 'הוספת תמיכה לפאנל אישי של ווקומרס',
            'description' => 'הכנסת פאנל אישי בעת לחיצה כולל התחברות, הרשמה, הזמנות ועוד...'
          ) );
```

[image]

for those who trying to figure out which language wrote in the label and description, its Hebrew.

I tried to create a JavaScript that tells the div to append another div with title class (h1 or h2) and it did not work, i tried to add HTML output to the array mentioned in the add_setting and control which did not work as well, i even tried foolishly to add pure HTML inside the code and probably PHP critical error.